# session_name breaks my site?

Tags: session, nginx, php

After reading through the PHP manual, I added `session_name('mysite');` to my code to ensure that collisions between sessions won't happen if I will run multiple apps in the future.

Unfortunately the `session_name()`-function call it kills my site completely . A fatal error is thrown (which appears in the error logs, but doesn't say anything!) and the below error is shown in the browser:

I have PHP-FPM running along with suhosin+nginx at a freshly installed Ubuntu VM. **What am I doing wrong?**

[image: NGINX]

Comment: configuration issue? http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.name

Comment: I'd be surprised to see a session handler causing `502`.

Comment: Could the value `mysite` actually be `mysite.com`? According to [this comment](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-name.php#86000) it would break everything.

Comment: Hi! Nope - only characters a-z being used

Comment: @kapep `session.name specifies the name of the session which is used as cookie name. **It should only contain alphanumeric characters**.` And period is not an alphanumeric character http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alphanumeric

Comment: what does the error log message say?

Comment: `PHP Fatal error:  Exception thrown without a stack frame in Unknown on line 0`

Comment: http://drupal4hu.com/node/222 ;) hope that will help

Comment: @maggie not sure what you are trying to tell me. `mysite` is obviously a place holder, so one might assume he accidentally used the host name. Of course `.` isn't alphanumerical. Just because the documentations mentions it, it doesn't make anyone infallible.

Comment: Unfortunately not. Already tried to wrap the `session_name`-call into a try/catch block before posting, but the Exception isn't caught regardless :(

Comment: only the `session_name` call or evertything? if not tried try to wrap everything. your `session_name` call could "impact" later

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments on the [session_name doc page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-name.php), there are some issues w/ session_name that can cause your site to break:

1. Make sure that you call `session_name` **before anything else**, including `session_start`
2. Make sure there are no periods in your session name (i.e.: don't use "mysite.com" as your session name)

Comment: Hi Brian! Yep! session_name is the very first line in my script that's called and it only contains characters a-z

Comment: `session.name specifies the name of the session which is used as cookie name. **It should only contain alphanumeric characters**.` And period is not an alphanumeric character http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alphanumeric

Comment: I think that was just what Brian said :)