# how to manage php session effectively

Tags: php, ajax, session, session-cookies

I have am trying to manage active php session:

**Description:**

I have custom php pages all of them have at the top:

```
<?php
include 'session_handler.php';
?>
```

the file "session_handler.php" has the following:

```
<?php
if (!defined('copyright_files')){
header("Location:error.php");
exit();
}
?>
<?php
session_name("sessionhash");
session_start();
error_reporting(E_ALL);
include 'connect.php';
?>
```

I am using json to fetch data from pages and the content is requested via ajax.

I am also calling "checksession.php" at regular interval via ajax (IN BACKGROUND), eg: every 5 seconds.

**Problem:**

The problem is that I loose session unexpectedly.

Earlier the "session_handler.php" had:

```
<?php
session_name("sessionhash");
session_start();
session_regenerate_id(true);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
include 'connect.php';
?>
```

Which was creating more sessions for the same, so I removed the "session_regenerate_id", It is only used once now.

I am using the following in .htaccess

```
php_value session.cookie_lifetime 18000
php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 18000
```

Comment: what happens when you put session_start() before session_name() ?

Comment: Are you sure afik you have to call session_name() before session_start()

Comment: I think you're right. Looks like session_name should be called before session_start: http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-name.php  & this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7176666/session-name-breaks-my-site

Answer (score 0):

may be...
check if the php session id value in cookie sent with ajax is ok.

Comment: I have checked every thing, thats why asking you guys may be I am missing something.

Comment: i had some trouble with session in the past with iframe, and flash upload. one request without cookie session id and a new session was started, all session value was lost.